# Can we install the Private key (.p12) certificate from Server to Client?

Tags: certificate

Am trying to distribute the Private Key(.p12) certificate from Server to Client using GPO. It's been reflected in my client after invoking the gpupdate /force command in the Client Machine. 
Here i tried winhttpcertcfg.cer to give the Access for the certificate to everyone. 
 but i got an error, that states the user who installed the certificate can only access.

My question here is;
1. Can we install the Private key (.p12) certificate from Server to Client ?

2. Is there anyway to install the certificate without manpower in windows machine?

Comment: Private keys aren't usually shared between computers (hence "private"); so there's probably got a good bulk-distribution model.  Perhaps if you said why you wanted do this there'd be a suggestion as to an alternative solution.

Comment: i have an appplication which uses, LocalMachine store certitifcate, the Admins user is working nicely. But for standard user, itz not, that's why am asking